# How to query a dictionary that looks uniterable?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-queryset

This is my views.py

```
def best_selling_items_view(request):
    data = Cart.objects.all()
    product_obj = Product.objects.all()      
    best_selling = []
    for item in data:
        best_selling.append(item.products.all()) 

    best_selling_unique = best_selling
    unique_set = []
    for product in best_selling_unique:
        for item in product:
            unique_set.append(item)
    # print(set(unique_set))

    unique_of_unique = list(set(unique_set))
    print(unique_of_unique)

    context={

    'object': unique_of_unique, 
    }
    return render(request, 'carts/best-selling.html', context)
```

When I try  to query the context dict, I get TypeError at /best-selling/ that *Product object is not iterable*.
Here is what the unique_of_unique dict looks like from the error page

```
unique_of_unique    
[<Product: G-string>,
 <Product: Condoms>,
 <Product: T-shirt>,
 <Product: Sex robot>,
 <Product: saleh>,
 <Product: zap nacks>]
```

Cart model:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    products    = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)
    subtotal    = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    total       = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)

    updated     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects     = CartManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Product model:

```
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug            = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    description     = models.TextField()
    price           = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, default=39.99)
    image           = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_path, null=True, blank=True)
    featured        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active          = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects         = ProductManager()
```

Comment: That is not a dictionary, that is a `QuerySet`, and *individual* `Product`s are indeed not iterable.

Comment: Can you please share your `Cart` and `Product` model, you make it too complex. Django can help you filter on related objects.

Comment: The set looks iterable though

Comment: @Fnechz: please [edit] your question.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have edited it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to query the database like that. In fact this will result in an *N+1 problem* where for every `Cart` object, you query the database once. If the number of `Cart`s grows, then of course the database will grow as well.

You can obtain a `QuerySet` of distinct `Product` objects with the following query:

```
Product.objects.filter(cart__isnull=False).distinct()
```

**EDIT**:

You can obtain the `Product` that is in the largest number of `Cart`s with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

best_product = Product.objects.annotate(
    n_cart=Coalesce(Count('cart'), Value(0))
).order_by('-n_cart').first()
```

Comment: I understand it now, but I want a method that would return the best selling items and then display them in django templates. How then would I query  the Queryset you gave me. PS: Im stil a newbie to django

Comment: @Fnechz: best *per* cart, or over all these products. What is the "best" selling item? How do you order these?

Comment: Over all the products **in all carts**

Comment: @Fnechz: so you want the `Product` that is in *most* `Cart`s?

Comment: that seems to work, so how will I render the best_product in the django template?

Comment: @Fnechz: you pass it in the context (so something like `{'best_product': best_product }`, and then in the template `{{ best_product }}` is a `Product` object, so you can render `{{ best_product.title }}` for example.